# How to Update json file that is Data lake using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

1. we have a json file in the blobstorage we have to update the json file by giving the table name as input
2. update the particular given table    lasttrackingver  by passing the value
   In AZUREDATA Factory
3. "lastupdate" column in the sample data needs to change for any table updated
4. "tableupdate" needs to update the particular  input table we are givingtable
   sample data looks like

```
{
  "name" :"job schedule", 
  "lastupdate": "2023-09-15"T13:00:00.000000Z", 
  "schedule":{
  
    "BANKtable" :
    [
      { 
        "tablename":"mani",
       "pipeline":"manikana",
      "tableupdate": "2023-09-15"T13:00:00.000000Z",
   
     "lasttrackingver":"0"
      },
    { 
        "tablename":"ganesh",
       "pipeline":"ganeshkulkarni",
      "tableupdate": "2023-09-15"T13:00:00.000000Z",
   
     "lasttrackingver":"0"
      },
   { 
        "tablename":"jagadesh",
       "pipeline":"jaga",
      "tableupdate": "2023-09-15"T13:00:00.000000Z",
   
     "lasttrackingver":"0"
      }
]
}
```

For example input :  tablename:ganesh
lasttrackingver=2

Output::::

```
{
  "name" :"job schedule", 
  "lastupdate": "TODAYSDATE", 
  "schedule":{
  
    "BANKtable" :
    [
      { 
        "tablename":"mani",
       "pipeline":"manikana",
      "tableupdate": "2023-09-15"T13:00:00.000000Z",
   
     "lasttrackingver":"0"
      },
    { 
        "tablename":"ganesh",
       "pipeline":"ganeshkulkarni",
      "tableupdate": "TODAYSDATE",
   
     "lasttrackingver":"2"
      },
   { 
        "tablename":"jagadesh",
       "pipeline":"jaga",
      "tableupdate": "2023-09-15"T13:00:00.000000Z",
   
     "lasttrackingver":"0"
      }
]
}
```

We are not getting correct approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create parameters both at dataflow level as well as pipeline level
   [image]
2. Drag a dataflow activity and in Parameters tab select the value for dataflow parameters as pipeline parameters so that you can pass the value during the runtime while you debug the pipeline
   [image]
3. In the dataflow, add a source transformation , point the dataset to the json file in ADLS and select 'Array of document' in the json settings
   [image]
4. Add a flatten transformation and unroll by BANKtable and select all the underneath column and preview the flattened data which could appear as tabular format. Click on plus symbol and add new branch out of flatten transformation
   [image]
   [image]
5. Add filter transformation in both the branches , one with expression : `tablename==$p_tablename` and the other with expression : `tablename!=$p_tablename`

**Filter1 output:** [image]
**Filter2 output:** [image]
6. Add a derived column transformation attached to filter1 having expression as  `lasttrackingver`= `$p_lasttrackingver` to update the lasttrackingver value to the parameter value
[image]
[image]
7. Add union transformation to union both branches data
[image]
[image]
8. Add aggregate transformation to group by name and lastupdate
[image]
9. Add derived column transformation to include `schedule` column having `BANKtable` array as subcolumn
[image]
10. Add select transformation to deselect BankTable column
[image]
11. Add Sink transformation and point to output json file

[image]